# Running StormSubmitter and Rabbitmq from console

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-storm

I am running storm and rabbitmq on ubuntu 12.04. rabbitmq is sending data which is being received by the storm spout. I am using the StormSubmitter class to specify a cluster.

I am using the command> bin/storm jar Rabbitmqstorm.jar RabbitmqTopology rabbittest
to run the storm topology.

But I am getting an exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/Consumer

This command is working fine when i am using LocalCluster class. However, i want to run this scenario in a cluster environment.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you don't have a required dependency (which it would be RabittMQ Java driver) on the cluster.  Just make sure that you have that dependency on the cluster.

Comment: I have exported the dependent jar file along with the topology jar.